# Custom DocumentPaginator and DocumentViewer WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, pagination, documentviewer, xpsdocument

I have a custom `DocumentPaginator`, that creates a table with some values and repeats table header in the beginning of every page. (Similar as [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/888/wpf-printing-part-2-pagination).)
How can i show pages generated by it in `DocumentViewr`?

I believe first i need to create an `XpsDocument`.
So i tried to use `XpsDocumentWriter`:

```
var xpsw = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDocument);
xpsw.Write(paginator);
```

But it doesn't work.
Does someone have any ideas how to do it?

Comment: *But it doesn't work.*  Well, that's certainly informative.  By the way, pagination is **hard**.  There are many things that can go wrong, and for many reasons.  If you can't narrow down the issue or be more detailed in your question, you probably won't get an answer.

Comment: It crushes with the following exception: **"FixedDocument must contain at least one FixedPage."**. On the line: `xpsw.Write(paginator);`.

Comment: Well, the paginator isn't providing any actual `FixedPage`s.  Not sure why, however.  A bit of debugging might help.

Comment: Thank you, Will. The problem was that `PageCount` wasn't implemented correctly.

Comment: You can provide a (at least a couple paragraph) description of the solution and close out the question, and you can close this out.  Not required, but [it can help your account's status.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121087/automatically-redirect-or-block-meta-questions-regarding-question-bans)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `Paginator.PageCount` overridden property wasn't implemented correctly. 
It used to return a negative number, so `Paginator.GetPage` method couldn't provide any pages.